# Using reflection to dynamically query an assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflection, assemblies

I am having difficulty with using reflections dynamically eg. query a .exe file without requiring a reference to be added for every assembly which I wish to query against.

So for instance, the code below is the regular way to get a hold of a class to then be checked.

```
AssemblyName assembly_name = new AssemblyName( "Name" );
```

The issue is not adding the argument in to the code but the code requirng direct reference to the new assembly to check against.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "query"

Comment: I want my exe to be able to run against different built assembly's so query refers to me sending in parameters to a selection of different assemblies for instance.

Comment: please show some code... what is your goal exactly ? what is not working ? any error messages/exception ?

Comment: No errors but il give all these ideas a try on next build. thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're really just trying to load an assembly at execution time. Look at [`Assembly.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) and [`Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyload.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "query".  If you want to know how to create an instance from an assembly using reflection, here is an example:

```
// From within the current assembly
public CartesianType CreateInstance(string fullyQualifiedClassName)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type target = assembly.GetType(fullyQualifiedClassName, true, true);

    return (CartesianType)Activator.CreateInstance(target);
}

// From an external assembly already referenced in your project
public SomeClass CreateInstance(string fullyQualifiedClassName)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SomeClass));
    Type target = assembly.GetType(fullyQualifiedClassName, true, true);

    return (SomeClass)Activator.CreateInstance(target);
}
```

All other methods must use `Load` or `LoadFile`, `LoadFrom` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something like [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil). It's a library (available on Windows and other platforms) that allows to query metadata without the need to resolve all references.